# Error while upload content from one domain to another domain

Tags: asp.net, .net

I receive this error on page after uploading content from one website. I have website in two langauges and try to merge those websites. Website developed in dotnet.

This is the error message I received while try to connect the page.

/*Error message starts*/

**Server Error in '/' Application.**
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ]
   System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength) +12722924
   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) +130
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +42
   MaharajaDrivers.BLL.DAL.DecriptPassword(String str) +10
   MaharajaDrivers.ViewPackages.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +159
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

/*Error Message end*/

Please help me to fix this issue.

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: you have to share the action where this is happening, only the stack trace doesnt help without the code

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me... How are you generating that base64?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. When I try to open a item from category page. I receive this error.... Normally the items in that page are opening successfully but some items in that page shows this error message.. Hope I explain clearly.